# Misplaced centroid in clusters

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, octave, k-means, centroid

So I have a few clustering algorithms implemented, and I'm supposed to create an algorithm to normalize the data and compare clustering with and without normalization.

What I have implemented is pretty simple, just the Min-Max normalization (I'm using Matlab btw):

```
 function [dataNorm] = nMinMax(data)
 [x, y] = size(data);
 dataNorm = zeros(x, y);

 for j = 1:y
     m = min(data(:,j));
     M = max(data(:,j));
     for i = 1:x
         n = (data(i,j) - m)/(M-m);
         dataNorm(i,j) = n;
     end
 end  
 end
```

And this is what what I get from a clustering w/o normalization:

[image]

Now it's where it gets strange, after the normalization, this is what I get:

[image]

The clusters are the same, when I thought it should have improved the results...

So my question is, is there a problem with my algorithm or am I interpreting the results the wrong way? And if I am, what should the cluster look like after the normalization?

Comment: if i understand correctly, your normalization should make the values go from 0 to 1. However in the second plot the values are from 0 to 6. it seems like you have plotted non-normalized data and centroids for normalized data.

Comment: the cluster should look the same after normalization. however in your case since you are normalizing each column separately, it is difficult to say how the final result will compare to original result except that the normalized values will range from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your second **plot** is incorrect.

You are plotting the *normalized* cluster centers but the *unnormalized* data set. Your data should be in the [0:1] range after normalization, which it obiously isn't - but your cluster means are. Noticed that they are within the 0:1 box?

No wonder they don't match. Either plot the normalized data set, or apply a reverse normalization to your cluster centers to get their unnormalized position.

However, your original data set is "almost square". Both the X and Y axes have the same value range of approximately -6 to +6; and the difference in X and Y clearly is smaller than the cluster separation. So it is not surprising if you do not see any effect of the normalization on this data set. Try a harder data set, where the axes are scaled substantially different, clusters have different sizes (in number of objects), extend (i.e. spatial size) and shape, and the clusters are less clearly separated.

Comment: Thanks, corrected that problem, and the clusters still look the same, but this isn't a problem aparently :)

Comment: No, as your X and Y axis have approximately the same value range, a linear min-max normalization should have next to no effect on your toy dataset. Try using one where the X and Y axes are scaled very differently!